# Improting a CSV file in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

Hi how do i insert a csv file into the database. the table has the following columns.

```
database: appwarehouse
table:application table
column: app_id, app name
```

this is my code for the view

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>some_controller/uploadBulk" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">     
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="classname"><br>            
</form>
```

This is my code for controller

```
public function uploadBulk(){
    $this->load->model('some_model');
    /*
        * similar to $name = $_POST['name'];
    */
    $file = $this->input->post('file');

    $success = $this->some_model->insertBulkApp($file);
    /* i DONT REALLY KNOW THE CODE JUST INSERT SOME CODE IN HERE */

    if($success == TRUE)
        $this->insert_page(TRUE);
    else 
        $this->insert_page(FALSE);
}
```

And i also need the code for my model.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the model can be really simple

```
public function insertBulkApp($file) {
    // Name of the table you want to insert to
    $this->db->insert('application table', $file);
}
```

Inside your controller you can set an array where the keys will be equal to the columns name of the table you want to insert to

```
 // Column name of the table you want to insert to
 $file["app name"] = $this->input->post('file');
 $this->some_model->insertBulkApp($file);
```

**Edit**

You can go check the documentation online for more informations about codeigniter. [Codeigniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: what do you mean by the two comments?